# How to put a copy of a file in all folders using bash script?

Tags: bash, loops, copy, sh

I have one config file that I want to copy to all the folders of some location using bash script. Before I used such a line:

```
aws s3 cp ${CONFIG_FILE} ${S3_URI}config.json
```

It copied one file to my location on the server. Now I have multiple folders in this location and each one needs the config file.

How can I write a loop for that? I'm new in bash so it's a bit hard for me to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for d in $(find /base/path/of/your/target/dirs -type d); do cp your_file $d; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without doing `for loop` as `find` command can do this out of the box:

```
find /lookup/path/ -type d -exec cp config.json {} \;
```

What this command do is to search inside a specific path and get a list of directories then it will use `exec` to copy a file inside these directories one by one